# How supress Nginx CORS headers coming from backend server

Tags: angular, nginx, cors, prometheus

I'm using Nginx to both serve Angular 2 client and route rest API to a backend server.
On Angular development mode I use the regular 'ng server' and then I should add CORS support to Nginx which is this way requested only for rest API as an external server.

My Nginx conf is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
    root /path/dist-nginx;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location /prometheus/prometheus/ {
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        return 204;
      }
      if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }
      #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

- location /prometheus/prometheus is for api
- location / to serve Angular client

It's work perfectly with the first request:

```
http://localhost:3330/prometheus/prometheus/metrics
```

showing that at least the CORS settings work well.

but when the client executes the following request:

```
http://localhost:3330/prometheus/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=http_request_size_bytes
```

I got this issue in the browser:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
 http://local.appcelerator.io:3330/prometheus/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=http_request_size_bytes.
 The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,
 http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.  Origin
 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Looking at the header answer of the request i got:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Date
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:657
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sun, 11 Jun 2017 05:39:34 GMT
Server:nginx/1.13.1
```

So 3 CORS headers fields have been added in addition to mine:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS
```

Angular client requests directly Nginx, there is no one in the middle.

Direct curl of these two requests on nginx work perfectly.

if i execute the fist request :

```
http://localhost:3330/prometheus/prometheus/metrics
```

a second time after the one witch failed, i got no error, header fields are ok.

Seems that the issue is link to this request especially:

```
http://localhost:3330/prometheus/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=http_request_size_bytes
```

Seems that the backend server here prometheus adds itself some CORS headers when it answers to api requests on the url /api/v1

how i can get ride of them?

Thank you for any ideas which could help to understand what's happening there.

Comment: You said there's nothing in the middle, but what's `proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090/;` doing? Are you sure that code served by that isn't adding its own CORS headers?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, i can confirm that the added CORS fields came from prometheus backend.

So when i requested /prometheus/prometheus/metrics for instance, i don't get addition CORS field in header, but when i requested /prometheus/prometheus/api/v1 a got additional CORS fields in header

It's a Prometheus not consistent behavior and to solve that i had to create two separated locations one for /prometheus/prometheus/metrics handling CORS and one for /prometheus/prometheus/api/v1 which doesn't handle CORS